# Nesting loops on same array but skipping same element

Tags: ruby

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to find a more Rubyist way to achieve the following. Essentially, I want to try and iterate over every element `e` and apply `e.method(n)` for every \$n \in \text{array}\$, \$n \ne e\$. In order to determine whether or not \$n = e\$, I'll have to use an index comparison (really just test for reference equality as opposed to functional equality).

```
arr = [413, 321, 654, 23, 11]
(0...arr.length).each do |outer_i|
    (0...arr.length).each do |inner_i|
        next if outer_i == inner_i
        arr[outer_i].apply arr[inner_i]
    end
end
```

This reeks of Java/C++ and I can tell that this is not the Ruby way, but I can't seem to find an alternative. Any ideas to improve its Ruby-ness? I was thinking of `Array#product` but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: Since appears to be off-topic for Code Review in its current state, since the code you've posted is pseudo-code. See if you can reword it to be more [on-topic](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Flambino That's not pseudo code.. it will pass any Ruby interpreter (aside from the `apply` method)

Comment: The `apply` call is my complaint, since the code doesn't run, nor is the function of that method made clear. Hence, the code felt incomplete to me. Pseudo-code like if you'd had a `do_stuff` method. However, re-reading your question, and seeing tokland's answer, I've retracted my close-vote. I felt there wasn't enough to go on, and misunderstood a few things, but I was wrong.

Comment: @Flambino Either way, thanks for pointing out the pseudo-code rule; wasn't aware of that! I'll try to steer clear of non-legal code in the future

Comment: Did you patch the `Fixnum` class to define an `apply` method? That may be the most questionable practice in this code.

Comment: @Michael: You may delete the line `arr = [413, 321, 654, 23, 11]`, it's misleading, and just say that the elements in `arr` have a method `apply`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that you are just doing a permutation of two elements from a set, and there is an abstraction in the core for that, [Array#permutation(n)](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-permutation):

```
arr.permutation(2).each { |x, y| x.apply(y) }
```

Comment: Can't get much simpler than that!

Answer (score 1):

Some remarks if you don't want to use the `permutation`-method.

The loop with a counter on an array is not rubyesk. In ruby an iterator like `Array#each` is preferred (I added the apply-method to the code to make it runnable):

```
class Fixnum
  def apply(i)
    puts "%i  -- %i " % [self,i]
  end
end
arr = [413, 321, 654, 23, 11]

arr.each do |outer|
    arr.each do |inner|
        next if outer == inner
        outer.apply inner
    end
end
```

This works, unless the array contains an entry twice (e.g. `arr = [413, 321, 654, 23, 11, 11]`).

If you need the index you can use `Array#.each_with_index`:

```
arr.each_with_index do |outer, outer_i|
    arr.each_with_index  do |inner, inner_i|
        next if outer_i == inner_i
        outer.apply inner
    end
end
```

You may also replace the inner loop with an array without the element of the outer loop:

```
arr.each_with_index do |outer, outer_i|
  arr2 = arr.dup #Without dup you would change the original array
  arr2.delete_at(outer_i)
  arr2.each  do |inner|
      outer.apply inner
  end
end
```